# I can't declare a NSTimer in the GameScene class as it believes there is an "Extra Argument 'selector' in call

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, sprite-kit

As the title states, I am having trouble declaring a new timer in the GameScene class without an error. I am trying to declare a timer here so I can reference the timer in other functions.

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target:self, selector: Selector("beeTimer"), userInfo:nil, repeats: true)


func timerDo() {

    if (timer % 100 == 0) {

        runAction(SKAction.repeatAction(SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.runBlock(addEnemy1),
            SKAction.waitForDuration(10)
            ]), count: 1))

        runAction(SKAction.repeatAction(SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.runBlock(addEnemy2),
            SKAction.waitForDuration(10)
            ]), count: 1))
    }
}
}
```

Is it possible to do this? I keep getting: `Extra Argument 'selector' in call`

**EDIT** I have tried to follow the steps in the other similar question but it doesn't resolve my issue.

Comment: I have tried following the other question and I still can't resolve the issue! Thats why I am asking for help.

Comment: This is no a duplicate. The error you're getting because, in swift, you can't initialize property that depends on an unknown variable in the compile time. So you need to init it in the didLoadMethod.

Comment: And how can I call upon the timer. The ViewDidLoad is in my GameViewController but my timer code needs to be in GameScene.